# Php Monolog udp SocketHandler packet size

Tags: php, udp, logstash, monolog

I am using monolog logs and want to send it to logstash using udp protocol. When I send it with Monolog/Handler/SocketHandler - it sends just very small json data (it’s about 1000 bytes). Default udp max packet - 65535 bytes. Any suggestions how to send bigger json using SocketHandler (or some else).

Comment: did you find the solution?